# Char Count in C?

Tags: c

So I am getting 1 more extra character than I should when i compile this code, someone please tell me the stupid error i am doing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    char str[20];
    char A = 'a';
    char B = 'A';
    int count = 0, i;

    printf("Enter a string : ");
    fgets(str, 20, stdin);

    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (str[i] == A||B)
            count++;
    }

    if (count == 0)
        printf("\nCharacter A is not present");
    else
        printf("\nThere are %d A's in your string.", count);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (str[i] == A||B)` --> `if (str[i] == A || str[i] == B)`

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

/*    This is the issue (str[i] == A)||(str[i] == B)   */

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    char str[20];
    char A = 'a';
    char B = 'A';
    int count = 0, i;

    printf("Enter a string : ");
    fgets(str, 20, stdin);

    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (str[i] == A || str[i] == B)
        count++;
    }

    if (count == 0)
        printf("\nCharacter A is not present");
    else
        printf("\nThere are %d A's in your string.", count);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```